malloc(): corrupted top size on deleting an entry from binary file
I AM CREATING A SCHOOL MANAGEMENT SYSTEM . WHEN I TRY TO DELETE A STUDENT AFTER ADDING ONE I AM GETTING "malloc(): corrupted top size" ERROR .CANT FIND THE REASON.I AM A BEGINNER , HELP PLEASE
structure i created :
typedef struct {
    char name[NAME_LENGTH ];
    int age;
    int roll_no;
    char blood_group[BG_LENGTH];
} Student;

typedef struct {
    char school_name[NAME_LENGTH ];
    int classes;
    int *no_of_students;
    Student **students;
} School;

function to add student
void add_student(School *school, int class_id, int student_id)
{  
    if(school==NULL)
    {
        printf("\n INVALID SCHOOL POINTER\n");
        return;
    }
    if (class_id<0 || class_id >= school->classes )
    {
        printf("\nINVALID_CLASS_INDEX");
        return;
    }
    if (student_id<0 || student_id >= school->no_of_students[class_id] )
    {
        printf("\nINVALID STUDENT INDEX");
        return;
    }


    int roll_no;   

   printf("\nEnter roll number: ");    
     if (scanf("%d", &roll_no) != 1)
    {
        printf("\nInvalid input. Please enter a number.\n");
        clear_input_buffer();
        return;
        
    }
 load_students_from_bfile(school,  class_id,  student_id);



for (int i = 0; i < school->no_of_students[class_id]; i++) {
    // printf("Checking roll number at index %d: %d\n", i, school->students[class_id][i].roll_no);
    if (school->students[class_id][i].roll_no == roll_no) {
        printf("Found existing roll number: %d\n", roll_no);
        printf("Roll number already exists!\n");
        return;
    }
}
    school->students[class_id][student_id].roll_no = roll_no;
    printf("\nEnter student name: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", school->students[class_id][student_id].name);
    printf("\nEnter age: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &school->students[class_id][student_id].age) != 1)    {
        printf("\nInvalid input. Please enter a number.\n");
        clear_input_buffer();
        return;
    }  
int bg_choice;
printf("\nChoose your BloodGroup:\n\n1. A+\n2. A-\n3. B+\n4. B-\n5. AB+\n6. AB-\n7. O+\n8. O- \n\nYour Choice:  ");

if (scanf("%d", &bg_choice) != 1)
    {
        printf("\nInvalid input. Please enter a number.\n");
        clear_input_buffer();
        return;
    }     char bg[10];

    switch (bg_choice)
     {
     case 1:
     strcpy(bg,"A+");
     break;
     case 2:
     strcpy(bg,"A-");
     break;
     case 3:
     strcpy(bg,"B+");
     break;
     case 4:
     strcpy(bg,"B-");
     break;
     case 5:
     strcpy(bg,"AB+");
     break;
     case 6:
     strcpy(bg,"AB-");
     break;
     case 7:
     strcpy(bg,"O+");
     break;
     case 8:
    strcpy(bg,"O-");
    break;
     default:
   printf("\nInvalid Choice.\n");
             break;
    }
strcpy(school->students[class_id][student_id].blood_group,bg);
 printf("You choose blood_group : %s",school->students[class_id][student_id].blood_group);

    add_student_to_bfile(school,class_id,student_id);
}


void delete_student(School *school, int class_id, int roll_no) 
{
    if(school==NULL)
    {
        printf("\n INVALID SCHOOL POINTER\n");
        return;
    }
    if (class_id<0 || class_id > school->classes )
    {
        printf("\nINVALID_CLASS_INDEX");
        return;
    }
    if (roll_no<0 )
    {
        printf("\nINVALID ROLL NUMBER");
        return;
    }
 
    delete_student_from_bfile(school, class_id, roll_no) ;
}



3.MANAGE _ BINARYFILE.C

void load_from_bfile(School *school)
{
    if (school == NULL) {
        printf("\n INVALID SCHOOL POINTER");
        return;
        }
    FILE* bfptr=fopen("school.dat","rb");
    if(bfptr==NULL)
    {
        printf("\n not able to open file %s",strerror(errno));
        return;
    }
    
    int classes;
    char school_name[NAME_LENGTH];

    fread(&classes, sizeof(int), 1, bfptr);
    fread(school_name, sizeof(char), NAME_LENGTH, bfptr);
    strncpy(school->school_name, school_name, NAME_LENGTH);
    school->classes = classes;
    printf("******SCHOOL DETAILS******");
    printf("\nSchool Name: %s\n", school->school_name);
    printf("\nNumber of Classes: %d\n", classes);


        school->no_of_students = (int *)malloc(school->classes * sizeof(int));
        school->students = (Student **)malloc(school->classes * sizeof(Student *));


    for (int i = 0; i < classes; i++)
    {
        school->students[i] = (Student *)malloc(school->no_of_students[i] * sizeof(Student));

        int num_students;
        fread(&num_students, sizeof(int), 1, bfptr);
        school->no_of_students[i] = num_students;
        printf("\nClass %d - Number of Students: %d\n", i + 1, num_students);

     
    }

    fclose(bfptr);
}

void add_student_to_bfile(School *school, int class_id, int student_id)
{
    if(school==NULL)
    {
        printf("\n INVALID SCHOOL POINTER");
        return;
    }
   if (class_id<0 || class_id >= school->classes )
    {
        printf("\nINVALID_CLASS_INDEX");
        return;
    }
    if (student_id<0 || student_id >=school->no_of_students[class_id] )
    {
        printf("\nINVALID STUDENT INDEX");
        return;
    }


    char filename[20];
    sprintf(filename, "%d.bin", class_id+1); 
    FILE *bfptr = fopen(filename, "ab");
    if (bfptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nUnable to open file %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

    fwrite(&school->students[class_id][student_id], sizeof(Student), 1, bfptr);

    fclose(bfptr);

    printf("\nStudent details added  successfully.\n");

}

void delete_student_from_bfile(School *school, int class_id, int target_rollno) 
{
    if(school==NULL)
    {
        printf("\n INVALID POINTER");
        return;
    }

    if (class_id > school->classes) {
        printf("\nInvalid class index");
        return;
    }

    char filename[20];
    

    sprintf(filename, "%d.bin", class_id); 
    FILE *bfptr = fopen(filename, "rb+");
    if (bfptr == NULL) {
        printf("\nUnable to open file %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

    char temp_filename[20];
    sprintf(temp_filename, "%d.tmp", class_id);
    FILE *temp_bfptr = fopen(temp_filename, "wb+");
    if (temp_bfptr == NULL) {
        printf("\nUnable to create temporary file %s: %s\n", temp_filename, strerror(errno));
        fclose(bfptr);
        return;
    }

    Student student;
    int found = 0;
    int i=0;
    while (fread(&student, sizeof(Student), 1, bfptr) == 1) {
        i++;
        if (student.roll_no == target_rollno) {
            found = 1;
            printf("\nStudent with Roll No %d found and deleted.\n", target_rollno);
            for (int j = i; j < school->no_of_students[class_id] - 1; j++) {
                school->students[class_id][j] = school->students[class_id][j + 1];
            }

            school->no_of_students[class_id]--;
        } else {
            fwrite(&student, sizeof(Student), 1, temp_bfptr);
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        printf("\nStudent with Roll No %d not found.\n", target_rollno);
    }

    fclose(bfptr);
    fclose(temp_bfptr);

    remove(filename); 
    rename(temp_filename, filename);
}

OUTPUT:
TERMINAL OUTPUT SHOWING ERROR
IN MY CODE THE INPUTS ARE TAKEN USING STRUCTURES , THEN THEY ARE SAVED INTO A BINARY FILE ,SCHOOL RECORD HAS SEPARATE FILE,AND EACH CLASS HAS SEPARATE FILE.
NEED TO REMOVE THAT ERROR AND CORRECT MY CODE

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Association_with_shouting_or_yelling

Please don't SHOUT at us, it's rude.

As for the problem, you typically get something like that if you write out of bounds of your dynamically allocated memory. You need to make sure you never do that.

Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

And as a general tip to help with debugging and finding and fixing problems like this: Don't write large chunks of code all at once. Instead start with an empty main function. Build with extra warning enabled, treated as errors. Test the program and code in all possible ways. Then you add a very small bit of code, perhaps even just one or two lines. Build and test as before. And so on... This way, if there's a problem it's much easier to find it and solve it. Perhaps by creating a [mre].

Your caps lock key appears to be stuck.  You might want to replace your keyboard so that you can type lowercase letters.  No one wants to read an all-uppercase post.

Oh and while you show us a lot of code (too much code really), you forgot two important parts: The header files.

Also, please don't post pictures of text. Post text as properly formatted text. You can [edit] your question in order to improve it.

In function load_from_bfile:
for (int i = 0; i < classes; i++)
{
    school->students[i] = (Student *)malloc(school->no_of_students[i] * sizeof(Student));

    int num_students;
    fread(&num_students, sizeof(int), 1, bfptr);
    school->no_of_students[i] = num_students;
    printf("\nClass %d - Number of Students: %d\n", i + 1, num_students);

 
}

The malloc call uses the value of school->no_of_students[i]. However, that value is only set a couple of lines later. At the point of use, it has no value yet.

As the other answer mentioned, you are using no_of_students in a certain class, which has not been set yet. Why don't you define a maximum size for the number of students in the class and then use no_of_students as a tracker for the people currently attending the class? Alternatively, you can store the no_of_students array at the end (and use fseek) or at the start. By doing this, you can load the number of students needed first before doing an allocation.
